# What's the difference between a cross join and an inner join with identical filter?

Tags: postgresql, inner-join, cross-join

Let's see a `cross join`:

```
select c1, c2, c3
from t1
cross join t2
where t1.f1 = t2.f2
```

and let's see an `inner join`:

```
select c1, c2, c3
from t1
inner join t2
on t1.f1 = t2.f2
```

What is the difference between the two statements in terms of performance, functionality and memory usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two queries are functionally identical, as is the following query:

```
select c1, c2, c3
from t1, t2
where t1.f1 = t2.f2
```

What follows is my personal opinion:

*Always* write inner joins with the `JOIN ... ON ...` or `JOIN ... USING (...)` syntax.
The advantages are:

1. It is immediately clear to the reader what you are doing and what the join condition is.
2. You can never forget to write a join condition, because you are required to write one.

   This protects you from queries that return 1 billion rows instead of 10000 just because you forgot some join conditions, which is a frequent beginner's mistake.

Also note that while for inner joins it doesn't matter if you write a condition in the `JOIN` or in the `WHERE` clause, it matters for outer joins.